# macOS host Problems with QEMU audio on Debian installation

Tags: macos, audio, debian, homebrew, qemu

I want to virtualize debian 11.2 with QEMU. However, the guest operating system has no audio. Since I'm blind and therefore work with a screen reader, it's important that the sound works. My host is a MacBook Pro 13 2020 with 2 GHZ quad-core Intel core i5 processor and 16 GB RAM. My operating system is MacOS Monterey 12.3.1.

I installed QEMU via Homebrew.

```
brew install qemu
```

Then I created a virtual hard drive.

```
qemu-img create -f qcow2 DebianHD.qcow2 40G
```

Next, I started the virtual machine.

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -machine type=q35,accel=hvf \
    -smp 2 \
    -hda DebianHD.qcow2 \
    -cdrom ./debian-11.2.0-amd64-netinst.iso \
    -m 8G \
    -vga virtio \
    -usb \
    -device usb-tablet \
    -display default,show-cursor=on
```

After the virtual machine started, I selected "Install with speech synthesis".

The installer now displays the following:

```
No sound card detected after 80seconds…
Can not do software speech synthesis… Press enter to continue anyway
```

I think I need to add a boot option for QEMU to have access to the sound card. In VirtualBox I was able to use Debian with screen reader.

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Thank you for your help.

Tom

Answer (score 0):

solution

qemu-system-x86_64 
-machine type=q35,accel=hvf 
-smp 2 
-hda DebianHD.qcow2 
-cdrom ./debian-11.2.0-amd64-netinst.iso 
-m 8G 
-vga virtio 
-usb 
-device usb-tablet 
-device intel-hda -device hda-output 
-display default,show-cursor=on

the missing boot option is

```
-device intel-hda -device hda-output \
```